# Running of exe file of .NET application in Windows 7 embedded stopped

Tags: c#, frameworks, .net-4.0, windows-7-embedded

I have created a windows application in Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4.0, in an operating system windows 8.1.
I am trying to execute an .exe file of my application in windows 7 embedded with .Net Framework 4.0 other application, (I have all the dlls, all environment set).
But it's not working it says

> Problem caused the program to stop working will close the program.

In the event log the following is written:

> Activation context generation failed for "c:\program files\remote utilities - host\Printer\x64\VPDAgent_x64.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyTo‌​ken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3‌​b",type="win32",vers‌​ion="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: Are you able to open the Event Viewer on that machine?

Comment: Yes I am able to Open it

Comment: Then please give us what is written in there - there should be an event with an exception + stack trace in there...

Comment: Activation context generation failed for "c:\program files\remote utilities - host\Printer\x64\VPDAgent_x64.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: I would say missing  dependency. Install MSVCP on that machine.

Comment: ok Thank you. hope it will work